# How to do grouping in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am developing an application in *Java* which extract reports in PDF and EXCEL using *iReport (3.7.2.)*. One of these reports is necessary to have data grouped . and only found the old versions with resolutions that not used. Can anyone tell me some way to extract the reports with their proper groupings?

Below the print screen of my query where I extract the data submitted with this grouping. My question is if is possible to do this in *iReport* and how? Or an idea how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any image attached, but Jasper Reports do offer this possibility. They are called (guess how?) Jasper Groups (you can google a bit for them by the way).

Anyway, there is another question about them where it is clarified in simple words, take a look at it: [Grouping records in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450634/grouping-records-in-jasperreports) . 
You said you're using iReports, so if you don't understand the explanations in the above question, this should come in help: [The Groups](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/groups) (Note that the dialog interface might vary a bit for different versions of iReport, but the procedure of creating groups with it
is basically the same).

Hope this helps.