# Multiple sum column

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using *JasperReports* with *iReport* to generate exports on my website.

Until now I successfully created many 'basic' reports with this format :

```
Title

Number | date | value

1 | 2014-08-10     | 42   `// with this part beeing programaticaly repeated`

2 | 2014-08-15 | 84

3  | 2014-09-05    | 24
```

---

What I need to do now, is to add a sum line for each months like this :

```
Title

Number | date | value

1 | 2014-08-10     | 42

2 | 2014-08-15 | 84

**SUM  | 2014-08 | 126**  `// I want to add this line at the end of every month`

3  | 2014-09-05    | 24

**SUM | 2014-09 | 24**
```

I haven't been able to find anything on internet because I don't know how to formulate my question. Everything I tried just add the 'sum column' after each basic column witch isn't what I'm trying to do.

Is there a functionality I missed or a trick to realize this ?

**EDIT :**

It isn't a *Java* but a *JasperReports/iReport* problem. Once I know how *JasperReports* allow to do it, I'll find how to do it in Java.

Comment: You can use grouping. [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer) & [Grouping records in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14450634/876298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question here on SO that you can look at [How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer) I have used this quick [Google search](https://www.google.co.za/#q=jasper%20reports%20variable%20reset%20type%20example) to find more references.

You can also look at the demos that are provided with the [Jasper Reports Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.6.0/jasperreports-5.6.0-project.tar.gz/download) archive, for example: `jasperreports-5.6.0/demo/samples/jasper/reports`. There is also documentation on the [JR web site](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/) that explain a bit more.

This should give a basic idea how to do the sum part. For doing it over the whole year's data and calculating the sum per month would require a grouping on the month which resets the variables every time the month of your date changes. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450634/grouping-records-in-jasperreports) might be overkill for what you want, more can be found with [this search](https://www.google.co.za/#newwindow=1&q=jasper+reports+group+by+variable+example).