# Grouping and sum records in JasperReport

Tags: sum, jasper-reports, grouping, export-to-excel

I have a list of records. All records have names, quantities and project names. Records can be duplicate in the list. I wanted to group the records by project name, so I used report group, but I also wanted to sum the same records within a project if there are duplicate ones.

Excel sheet now:

project name: 123 (in Group header)

Name           Quantity (in Group header)

item1                 15     (in Detail band)

item2                  5     (in Detail band)

item2                  7    (in Detail band)

item3                 11   (in Detail band)

Excel sheet I prefer:

project name: 123 (in Group header)

Name           Quantity (in Group header)

item1                 15     (in Detail band)

item2                 12     (in Detail band 5+7)

item3                 11   (in Detail band)

I use sql query. I tried to sum up the records in sql, but then I could not group the records by project name, since all records were summed without grouping by project name.

I found this: 
[Grouping records in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450634/grouping-records-in-jasperreports)

But this topic deals only with grouping and not summing within group

I hope someone can show how to set ireport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been suffering to find answer for a week and now that I'd posted my question here, I found a solution shortly that.

In sql query "Select item.item_name, project.project_name, sum(inventory.item_quantity) ... From project, item, inventory ... Where (project.projectid = inventory.projectid) and (item.itemid = inventory.itemid) ... Group By project.project_name, item.item_name..."

Adding report group in ireport: (in Report Inspector view) right click on report and select Add Report Group > Select group by: project.project_name > next: add group header and footer.

I use Netbeans 8.2 and IReport 5.5